# Is there support for "amazon-sqs-java-temporary-queues-client" with SqsAsyncClient?

Tags: asynchronous, netty, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-java

I am using SQS temporary queue with request/response pattern which uses SqsClient (under the hood it supports Apache HTTP client only). I am exploring to migrate the implementation to use netty to leverage on non-blocking way of working but aws sdk doesn’t seem to have support for that.
Anyone can advise if there is way to use netty with request/response pattern ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-temporary-queues-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Currently trying to use the Async client and provide custom implementation of requestor and responder but checking if AWS has any sdk with that already.